# Week view show multiple days instead of hours

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

Is it possible to create a custom `resourceTimline` view where multiple days of the week are shown - similar to the default month view (`resourceTimelineMonth`) - instead of just a few slots of a day?

So basically instead of this:

[image: Daily view]

I would like to have something like this:

[image: Week view]

... but only 5 days shown.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-settings

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-custom-view-demo (which also has source code if you click the "Edit in CodePen" button in the top right corner).

Comment: @ADyson - this is not what I am looking for - even the 10 days view in the demo shows the hours / slots instead of the days. I'm looking for something like the month view but with just 5 days, so that I get an overview of these 5 days, without scrolling through them.

Comment: The point was to indicate to you how you could start to customise it, and that all the info you need to complete your task is already available in the documentation and demos if you take the time to look through it in detail. I should perhaps have added https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotDuration too - it already appears in the source code of the demo (in the ":15 slots" view), so you can see what effect it has, did that not make you curious? Please take the time to read the docs and discover all the options available to you. Then you wouldn't need to wait days for answers here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom view definition as follows should do what you need:

```
  resourceTimelineFive: {
    type: 'resourceTimeline',
    buttonText: '5 Days',
    slotDuration: { days: 1 },
    duration: { days: 5 }
  },
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/abdwOXO

See the following documenation links:

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-settings

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotDuration

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/duration

and the demo at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-custom-view-demo for more information.

Comment: `slotDuration` is what I was missing - thanks for the help.